# Mapping the values against a dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

[image: Can someone explain why am I not getting the desired output of a single integer in the AIOT columns?[1]]
Can someone explain why am I not getting the desired output of a single integer in the AIOT columns?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? What should be the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your code replaces each `'AIOT'` by the **whole series** `df.A*df.B*...`. Therefore you see the same numbers across all values. Probably you mean:

```
df['checkvalidation'] = np.where(df['Course'].eq('AIOT'), 
                                 df.A*df.B*df.C*df.D*df.E,
                                 np.nan)
```

Comment: and what if I want to map multiple values i.e AIOT, AI, CNC etc?

Comment: Look at np.select